# Why does my recursive function always use the same random numbers?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write something that simulates the Martingale betting system. If you're not familiar with this, it's a "sure thing!" (not a sure thing) betting system for coin-toss games where you double your bet each time you lose, hoping to win back all your lost money upon the first win.

So your bets would go $10 -> loss -> $20 -> loss -> $40 -> loss -> $80 -> win! -> $10...

Simple, right? I figure the logic will be:

1. Have a wallet variable that starts at $1,000.
2. Make a bet.
3. Flip a coin with `rand(0..1)`. 0 will be a loss and 1 a win.
4. If I win, add the bet to my wallet. If I lose, subtract the bet from my wallet, and then issue a new bet for twice the previous.

I write this as:

```
def flip(bet)
    if rand(0..1) == 0 then
        $balance += bet
    else
        $balance -= bet
        flip(bet*2)
    end
end
```

Then I run `flip(10)` a thousand times just to see how effective this betting system is.

The problem is that I always get the exact same results. I'll run the program ten times, and the first five results will always be 1010, 1020, 1030, 1040, 1050... So something's wrong. But I can't really see what; the logic seems fine to me.

Just to test things out, I removed the recursive call, the line `flip(bet*2)`. Instead, I just ran a thousand regular bets. And that behaves the way you'd expect, different results every time.

So what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the logic it looks as if it will recursively bet until you win. So it looks like your balance is going up by 10 every time, hence the "1010, 1020, 1030, 1040, 1050".

If you put a `puts $balance` before the `flip(bet*2)` line you can see the balance going up and down.

I guess that's the point of the betting system. I don't think there is anything wrong with the random part of the method.

Comment: Damn, that didn't even occur to me and now I feel stupid. Of course that's it. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Your result is exactly what you expect with "sure thing" betting, because you allow `$balance` to go negative, so the better is not limited in any way (effectively they have infinite resources). The strategy will always exit $10 up on last balance, due to losing e.g. 10,20,40 dollars, then adding 80. Because you allow negative balance, the better is allowed to continue this - whilst a model could notice if they lost 6 games in a row (1 in 64 chance), then they would be down to $370, and not able to make the next bet at $640.

Add something to catch running out of money, and you should see a difference in how many bets it will take before that happens, or what the losing value of `$balance` is (i.e. you can demonstrate this way that the "sure thing" strategy is flawed - because for every 63 wins of $10, there is a single loss of $630 to perfectly balance it)